# Using require.js to load something before onload

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I see this question was asked here

[load javascript file before onload with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188571/load-javascript-file-before-onload-with-requirejs)

But the solution there doesn't fit my situation and so I'm wondering if there is a different solution. I can't build with deps and make my code come last because I'm making a library/utility, not an app.

I'm working on the [WebGL-Inspector](https://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/). It works by wrapping `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext` and if it sees a `"webgl"` it then does its thing wrapping the context and allowing you to inspect it.

The WebGL-Inspector works in 3 modes

1. As a browser extension
2. As a loader + large compiled script
3. As a loader + original source (many many scripts)

To use it in modes #2 or #3 above you just insert

```
<script src="core/embed.js"></script>
```

Somewhere in the top of your HTML. Because it loads synchronously~ish it will have wrapped `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext` before whatever scripts come after it.

These last 2 modes are mostly for debugging/development of the WebGL-Inspector itself. Especially mode #3 because we can edit the inspector's code and refresh the page immediately to see the result, no build step.

I'm in the process of switching to using AMD for all of the WebGL-Inspector. We're using this because we can use webpack to make #2 but still follow the same dev workflow allowing us it use mode #3 above just change the script tag to

```
<script src="core/require.js" data-main="core/embed.js"></script>
```

The problem is this no longer works because whatever other code unrelated to the WebGL-Inspector itself runs before `core/embed.js` has loaded and so calls `someCanvas.getContext` before we've had a chance to wrap it.

My current solution is sadly to hack in a delay of 1.5 seconds on whatever demo we're using

```
<script src="core/require.js" data-main="core/embed.js"></script>
<script>
// wait 1.5 seconds for embed.js to load and pray :(
window.onload = setTimeout(reallyRunWebGLCode, 1500);
...
</script>
```

The previous non-AMD loader doesn't have this async issue. Somehow it manages to load 60 or so .js files before `window.onload` fires. Is there a way to get require.js to do the same? Or maybe I need to write my own loader?

To put it another way, the issue is as it is now the user adds a single `<script>` line and **makes no other changes to their code** and it works. When they're done they remove the single script line.

Switching to AMD/require.js the user is now required to add a single script **and re-write code**. In my tests went from

```
window.onload = myapp;
```

to

```
require.config({ baseUrl: "/core" });
require("./embed", myapp);
```

It's minor but now the app is broken when you remove the `<script>` tag and has to be put back as it was. Requiring those changes is what I'm trying to avoid if possible. In fact with the original style you don't even have to remove the script tag, just run your app in an environment where the script doesn't exist, it will fail to load and your app will run as normal where as with the require method it will fail if the script doesn't exist.

I can require even more code

```
if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof define === 'function' and define.amd) {
  require.config({ baseUrl: "/core" });
  require("./embed", myapp);
} else {
  window.onload = myapp;
}
```

But that's even uglier. We went from adding a single script to requiring modifying your app.

Actually it gets even worse in the app I'm currently testing with. It uses a different loader for itself. When I run require version of the code above it fails because in this case require runs myapp before window.onload (strange). I end up having to do this

```
  var tryRunCount = 0;

  function tryRunApp() {
    ++tryRunCount;

    // check that tryRunApp has been called twice so we know
    // both onload and require have returned
    if (tryRunCount === 2) {
      myApp();
    }
  }

  window.onload = tryRunApp;
  require.config({ baseUrl: "/core" });
  require("./embed", tryRunApp);
```

That's *way way* more changes than I want to require users to make.

Comment: Define `reallyRunWebGLCode`  as a module and set embed.js as a dependency, so `reallyRunWebGLCode`  won't run until embed.js is loaded.
I am not sure if I understand you?! Do you really have to wait for the onload event to happen or do you need a certain script to be loaded before another?

Comment: It would look like this:
`require(["embed"], function(embed){reallyRunWebGLCode();})`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I doesn't work for me.

Comment: You don't actually mix require.js with other script tags, it's a design issue in your app. You have to migrate all the application code to make use of require.js. Mixing manual script references and require.js make no sense.
All your libs must be AMDfied or shimed.

Comment: You're missing the point of the question. I'm not making an app. I'm making something you insert in the page to debug your app. It needs to init before your app starts. It makes total sense. It's no different than the many polyfills you can add to your page that add missing features after which your app just runs as though the feature already exists. No integration required

Comment: Ok, this is a special case and afaik it will not be feasable without a hack, as AMD is async...